# Beautiful example of Salesforce Public Knowledge?

Tags: knowledge

We are redesigning our website and I want to share with our agency a good example of Salesforce public Knowledge.

Also, what resources should I share with them about how they can build knowledge into our new website? (Site will be built on Wordpress).

I haven't been able to find any good resources.

Answer (score 2):

Finding "Beautiful" and "good" examples would be a bit too subjective to answer here.

There a several examples listed in [Public Knowledge Base Examples?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtK5AAI)

> - Cisco: http://ciscocert.force.com/english/MainPage
> - Sparrow Broadcasting: http://marchex.force.com/reputationmanagement/knowledgeHome
>   http://gumtree.force.com/Help
>
> - Francois Lopitaux

.

> - http://bluejeans.com/support/knowledgebase
>
> - Mehdi CHAKER

In the latter it looks like they just iframed the http://bluejeans.force.com/KnowledgeSearch page into their site, which would be one viable option for Wordpress.